# How to add objects retrieved from fetch request to the state array in React and then update the view?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I'm trying to learn React by building a "movie search app". The main problem is that, I have an array of request URLs and I want to retrieve each object and push them into a state array and then update the state, however pushing to the state array doesn't work.

```
promises = arr.map(el=>fetch(requesturl).then(e=>e.json()))
result = promises => Promise.all(promises).then(value=>console.log(value));
```

The code looks something like this. Instead of printing them into the console, I want to save all of them and then update the view.

Apologies, if the question is unclear.

Comment: Right, you don't push to the state array. You should create a copy of the array, append the new resuts, then `setState` in the component with the new array

Comment: did you mean this?
`result = promises => Promise.all(promises).then(value=>{
      let arr = this.state.titles.concat(value);
      this.setState({titles : arr});
    });`

Comment: Yeah give that a try

Comment: Already did that, but the problem is that page is not loading. It looks like it is, but never finishes. I don't know why.
By the way, it is correct to call this method in componentDidUpdate? Because I did it so that the view would be updated when state changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it simply in a `then` after `Promise.all` like so:

```
const arr = ['google.com', 'youtube.com']

class MoviesList extend Component{
  state = { movies: [] }

  componentDidMount(){
    const promises = arr.map(el=>fetch(requesturl).then(e=>e.json()));
    Promise.all(promises).then(movies => this.setState(movies));
  }

  render(){
    return <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state.movies)}</div>
  }
}
```

[*`Worked jsfiddle`*](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/225852/)

Comment: Tried it, returns an empty array :/

Comment: @MensurQulami i added worked example :) Please check it